# XFCE swap Alt and Super (windows) key

Tags: xfce, keyboard-layout

I have tried many things to try to swap the `alt` and `windows` key on my Thinkpad X220 running LinuxMint 20.3 with xfce/xfwm4.

I've tried `setxkbmap -option altwin:swap_alt_win`, adding the following to `~/.xmodmap`:

```
remove mod1 = Alt_L
remove mod4 = Super_L
add mod1 = Super_L
add mod4 = Alt_L
```

and running `xmodmap ~/.xmodmap`

I've looked through the `Keyboard > Layout > Change Layout Option` to see what's available.

FWIW, `showkey` reports:

```
ALT keycode  56
SUPER keycode 125
```

and I've also tried manually setting this in `~/.xmodmap`:

```
keycode 56 = Alt_L
keycode 125 = Super_L
remove Mod1 = Alt_L
remove Mod4 = Super_L
add Mod1 = Super_L
add Mod4 = Alt_L
```

So far nothing has worked for me, any hints in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: X.Org or Wayland? What DM (or no DM)?

Comment: I am using Xfce - and WM is Xfwm4

Comment: Xfce is a Desktop Environment (DE), I asked about a Display Manager (DM) and whether you are using X.Org or Wayland.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have never had any luck getting *setxkbmap* to do what I want but have remapped keys at the kernel level with success.

First you need to know your input device and the key scan code.  The tool `evtest` can be used for that.

```
$ sudo evtest
No device specified, trying to scan all of /dev/input/event*
Available devices:
/dev/input/event0:  Power Button
/dev/input/event1:  Power Button
/dev/input/event2:  USB Laser Mouse
...
/dev/input/event7:  SONiX USB DEVICE
/dev/input/event8:  SONiX USB DEVICE Keyboard
/dev/input/event9:  SONiX USB DEVICE System Control
/dev/input/event10: SONiX USB DEVICE Consumer Control
/dev/input/event11: SONiX USB DEVICE
...
Select the device event number [0-31]:
```

Shown here are 5 devices that relating to keyboard and device number 7 happens to be the actual keyboard.  Trial and error to find this out.

Note the device id after selecting the keyboard.

```
Select the device event number [0-31]: 7
Input driver version is 1.0.1
Input device ID: bus 0x3 vendor 0xc45 product 0x5004 version 0x111
Input device name: "SONiX USB DEVICE"
Supported events:
...
```

The line `Input device ID` is what you need and this will be display just after you select your device.

When selected you can then hit some keys on the keyboard and an event will be logged for the key press and release.  If you don't see events being logged, you need to try selecting another device.  His `ctrl-c` when finished.

You will want to note the key code for *alt* and *super* after pressing them.  In my case the output for those keys presses looks like this:

```
Event: time 1643575346.666078, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 700e3
Event: time 1643575346.666078, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 125 (KEY_LEFTMETA), value 1
Event: time 1643575346.666078, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1643575346.766070, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 700e3
Event: time 1643575346.766070, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 125 (KEY_LEFTMETA), value 0
Event: time 1643575346.766070, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
...
Event: time 1643575369.928048, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 700e2
Event: time 1643575369.928048, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 56 (KEY_LEFTALT), value 1
Event: time 1643575369.928048, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1643575370.046045, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 700e2
Event: time 1643575370.046045, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 56 (KEY_LEFTALT), value 0
Event: time 1643575370.046045, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
```

Shown above, code 125 is for the super key, and 56 the left alt key.  Your values could be different.

Now you need to create a file to remap the desired keys.  Create a file in `/etc/udev/hwdb.d/` called `50-alt_super_swap.hwdb`.  Exactly what is is called is up to you, but you need a number at the beginning, the dash, and the extension.

In that file you will place the following:

```
# Input device ID: bus 0x3 vendor 0x13ba product 0x1 version 0x110
# evdev:input:b<bus_id>v<vendor_id>p<product_id>e<version_id>-<modalias>
evdev:input:b0003v13BAp0001*
  KEYBOARD_KEY_70038=125
  KEYBOARD_KEY_7007D=56
```

You need to modify the `evdev:input` line to reflect the device id printed out be `evtest`.  Note the translation and the upper/lower case.  If you don't get this line exactly correct, nothing will happen.

The `KEYBOARD_KEY_*` lines have their values in hexadecimal.  38 hex is 56 decimal, and 7D is 125.

```
$ sudo systemd-hwdb update
$ sudo udevadm trigger
```

It takes several seconds for the changes to be applied.  Along with finding the key swap worked you can also see if the changes were applied.

```
$ udevadm info /dev/input/event7
P: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.1/0000:0d:00.3/usb3/3-2/3-2:1.0/0003:0C45:5004.0005/input/input7/event7
N: input/event7
L: 0
S: input/by-path/pci-0000:0d:00.3-usb-0:2:1.0-event-kbd
S: input/by-id/usb-SONiX_USB_DEVICE-event-kbd
...
E: KEYBOARD_KEY_70038=125
E: KEYBOARD_KEY_70075=56
...
```

While I have not swapped alt and super myself, I have used this technique to [remap media keys](https://www.drque.net/?ArticleNumber=5829#_5829) using [this article](https://www.foell.org/justin/remapping-keyboard-keys-in-ubuntu-with-udev-evdev/) as a reference.

Comment: Thank you for this detailed response. It is very clear and makes sense. I did follow quite closely and managed to get the events to show in `udevadm` but it simply wouldn't work. In the end, I edited `Keyboard > Application Shortcuts` and changed the Shortcut for `xfce4-popup-whiskermenu` to `Alt L` and then in `Window Manager > Keyboard`, adjusted `Cycle Windows` to `Super + Tab` which sort of achieves what I was looking for.

Comment: Start always with: 

KEYBOARD_KEY_700

What is 700 ?

Comment: 70038 and 7007D are meant to be the key scancodes. These should be 700e3 and 700e2 for the given example, as per the last of the linked articles. Once I realised that, this is now working fine for me. I like that this solution is so low level that it should work regardless of window manager/desktop environment, and can be applied on a per-device basis.