# Fully disable specific keyboard key

Tags: linux, linux-mint, keyboard

My laptop keyboard has been water damaged and the left control key occasionally activates.

I am aware of xmapmod -e "keycode 37=" to disable the left control key. I seek to do something else as this causes a new problem. When I hold down any other key, e.g. 'a', a will be repeatedly typed *until left ctrl activates*. Although left control doesn't do anything now (thanks to xmapmod), it still interrupts key hold down.

I suppose that I need to stop the keyboard even listening for the left control key.

Does anyone have a fix for this? I am using linux mint. Thanks

Comment: A new desktop keyboard could be less than US$20. Would it be worthwhile just to get a new keyboard. Cost is more like US$80 for a laptop keyboard replacement so this might be more than you want to pay.

Comment: I forgot to mention that it is a built in laptop keyboard, hence my interest in the one key. Sadly it is a weird laptop and I can't find a keyboard replacement

Answer (score 0):

To "fully disable a key" in a sense that would help a water-damaged keyboard, I think you would have to reprogram the keyboard controller chip in the keyboard itself, or to physically modify the keyboard wire matrix to cut out/bypass the failing key.

Unless your keyboard is somehow special, it's probably not worth the trouble. If you want to try repairing the old one, get a replacement/substitute keyboard *first*: it's no fun to make an emergency run to a computer hardware store after you've discovered the hard way that you didn't know the trick to take the old keyboard apart non-destructively. (Been there, done that.)

Comment: okay it sounds like I'll just have to leave it then. It is a built in laptop keyboard which is why it is special. I can still type which I guess is good enough. Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to disable the key it can be done by remapping it at the kernel level (`udev`).  This is a rather an involved process.  [This article](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/map_scancodes_to_keycodes) has a section on how to block the sleep key, which you could use for your dead control key.

An outline of the steps:

1. Identify the input device ID of the keyboard using `evemu-describe`.
2. Identify the key code you wish to block using `evtest`.
3. Create a custom key code file in `/etc/udev/hwdb.d/50-block-ctrld.hwdb`.
4. Add the device id to top file.
5. Add `KEYBOARD_KEY_xxx=reserved` to file where `xxx` is the key code.
6. Apply the custom key code file using `systemd-hwdb` and `udevadm`.

Note that step 4 is complected because you must get the device id formatted correctly or nothing will happen.  [This article](https://www.foell.org/justin/remapping-keyboard-keys-in-ubuntu-with-udev-evdev/) has a good description on how to identify the keyboard event source and key codes.  I've also outlined the steps in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/688546/xfce-swap-alt-and-super-windows-key/688620#688620).

As others have pointed out there may be a better solution to your problem.   However should you really want to disable the key, this process should do it.

Comment: This sounds wonderful! I will try it. Thank you for your detailed answer!